# После перезагрузки отваливается диск на CentOS 8

Tags: linux, centos8

После перезагрузки операционки CentOS 8.3.2011 (установленная на виртуалке VMware ESXi 6.0 U3) один из дисков отваливается, приходится заново его монтировать.
Подскажите может кто-то знает в чём проблема? Или подскажите как выяснить в чём может быть проблема?
Благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно прописать параметры монтирования в `/etc/fstab`